# Differentiability at a point theorem for function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I came across this theorem in calculus: `If fx and fy exist near (a,b) and are continous at (a,b) then f(x, y) is differentiable at (a,b)`

What confuses me is that when I look at solutions to questions that require you to use the above theorem, the solutions only find fx and fy and determine if they are continous at (a,b) but `they don't show that those partial derivatives exist near (a,b) as well`. I want to know if finding fx and fy is and showing they are continous at (a,b) is enough and why?

Example question: Given f(x, y) = (x + 3y)^(1/2). Is the function differentiable at (1, 2).

Comment: The partial derivatives cannot be continuous without existing.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but can the partial derivatives exist at (a,b) but not near(a,b)

Comment: That is correct. If a function is only defined at the (isolated) point (a, b) then it is trivially continuous. – Perhaps you can give a  *concrete example* of a solution that you found, where you think that only continuity  at (a,b) but not existence in a neighborhood of (a,b) has been proven.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f_x(x,y)=(x+3y)^{-1/2}$ and $f_y(x,y)=3(x+3y)^{-1/2}$, both of which are continuous at $(1,2)$, $f$ is differentiable there.

Comment: But you didn't prove that it is continous near (1,2). Although it may be obviously continous.

Comment: @rert588 Note that you can obtain them as the composition of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

**As for the example question:**

Since we have:
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x+3y}$$
we take:
$$\begin{align*}
f_x(x,y)&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+3y}}\\
f_y(x,y)&=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x+3y}}
\end{align*}$$
which are both continuous - and, of course, well-defined - for every $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$  such that $x+3y>0$. So, since $(1,2)$ is such a point then abovementioned the theorem gives us that $f$ is differentiable at $(1,2)$.

**As for your comment about the existence of partial derivatives in an area around $(a,b)$:**

Consider the following function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$:
$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
y\left|x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\right| & x\neq0\\
0 & x=0
\end{array}\right.$$
Also, let 
$$A:=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\left| x\neq\frac{1}{2k\pi},\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\right.\right\}$$
It is clear that for $(x,y)\in A$, $f_x(x,y)$ does not exist, however, it does exist in $(0,y)$, for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Indeed,
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,y)}{x-0}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{y\left|x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|}{x}=\\
&=y\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left|x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|}{x}=\\
&=y\cdot0=\\
&=0
\end{align*}$$
since
$$\left|\frac{\left|x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|}{x}\right|\leq\left|x\right|\Leftrightarrow-|x|\leq\frac{\left|x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|}{x}\leq|x|$$
So, $f_x(0,y)=0$, for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$ but $f_x$  does not exist in any are around $(0,y)$ since it does not exist in $A$ and all points $(0,y)$ are accumulation points of $A$.

**Edit:**

You can now take $$g(x,y)=f(x,y)+f(y,x)$$
and have the same result for both $g_x$ and $g_y$.